# UIView exclusiveTouch: strange behaviour with UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I set a `UIButton`'s exclusiveTouch to `YES`, and it works fine (other views will not receive touch-events if I touch the button). The exception is that when I touch the `UIBarButtonItem` on the navigation bar, its action is triggered. It doesn't happen every time, but if you tap a bit higher on the `UIBarButtonItem`or just tap on the status bar close to the UIBarButtonItem, it happened.

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

UIBarButtonItem is not a subclass of UIView. So it doesn't have exclusiveTouch property and won't be affected by other views' exclusiveTouch.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in viewDidLoad

//Set exclusive touch on each navigationItem

```
for(UIView *navigationItem in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews)
{
   [navigationItem setExclusiveTouch:YES];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The weird behaviour only happened when I touched both the UIBarButtonItem and the status bar.So puzzled.